# About isomorphism of tensor maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, tensor-products

If $k=\Bbb Q(\omega)$ and $K=k(\sqrt[3]2)$ then the isomorphism $K\otimes_k K\to K^3$ goes as follows:
$$(a+b\sqrt[3]2+c\sqrt[3]4)\otimes\xi\mapsto
((a+b\sqrt[3]2+c\sqrt[3]4)\xi,
(a+b\omega\sqrt[3]2+c\omega^2\sqrt[3]4)\xi,
(a+b\omega^2\sqrt[3]2+c\omega\sqrt[3]4)\xi)$$
where $a$, $b$, $c\in k$, $\xi\in K$.

I want to show that this is isomorphism for this I need kernel to be trivial say tensor product map to (0,0,0) then we need to show that tensor product is 0 and then we need to show surjectivity how to show that? Also I want to know how K looks like is it same as Q($\omega$,$\sqrt[3]2$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what $\omega$ is but from context, I will assume its a third root of unity, so that $\mathbb{Q}(\omega, 2^{\frac{1}{3}})= K$ is the splitting field of $x^3-2$. Then we have that 
$$
K \otimes_k K = K \otimes_k k[x]/(x^3-2) = K[x]/(x^3-2) = K^3 
$$
since $x^3-2$ splits completely over $K$.

Comment: How we get K/(x^3-2) step and subsequent steps?

Comment: look up tensor product change of variables